# How to make controlled input using redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have one form component, in which we have one input field.once user enter a digit to input field and press submit, it should become two time of that input value.

```
import {Field} 'redux-form'; 
class Multiply extends React.Component {

  onInputChange = (stateKey) => (e) => {
    this.setState({ [stateKey]: e.currentTarget.value.trim() });
  };

  onSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ volume: this.state.volume *2  });
  };

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <Field
              name="volume"
              placeholder="Volume"
              component={renderInput}
              type="number"
              value={this.state.volume}
              onChange={this.onInputChange('volume')}
              validate={required}
            />

            <div>
              <button type="submit">
                Multiply by 2
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

once i click on button, value doesn't get change. but instead of `<field>` if i use `<input>` then it works fine. why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux Form inputs are dictated by their Redux state. This means you have to use its API to deal with them, as `Field` is giving your `renderInput` function an input value that equals whatever is in the Redux store for that field name.

What you'll need to do is

1. Inject the field value. A good way of doing so is by using [`formValues()`](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formvalues.md/)
2. Inject a function that dispatches a [`change` action](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-change-form-string-field-string-value-any-code-) for that form and for that field
3. Call such function in your button.

This is the gist of it:

```
const MyForm = ({ double }) => {
    /* Your form implementation, then */
    <button type="submit" onClick={double}>Double and submit</button>
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
    double: () => dispatch(change("foo", "number", props.number * 2))
});

const WithDoublingFunction = formValues("number")(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm));

export default reduxForm({
    form: "foo",
    // the rest of your config
})(WithDoublingFunction);
```

[Here's a working sandbox of such functionality](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmop5ynz3j)

Comment: I have one container component that wraps this component. That wrapper component connected to redux. In your Answer you use same component. how to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't understand you @MukundKumar

Comment: @mukund You pass action methods to update state in the container component as props to your child component (the form / UI I presume). Call action methods in the child and it'll update the state in the parent container component (that is connected to redux). If you've already got a smart / dumb component model in place, I'm surprised you ask this question as it's a really common pattern.